# Using cookies with lynx

Tags: linux, cookies, lynx

> lynx -cfg=cfg.file $URL

this works with the following contents of the .cfg file:

> SET_COOKIES:TRUE
>   ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES:TRUE
>   PERSISTENT_COOKIES:TRUE
>   COOKIE_FILE:cookie.file

however, this does not:

> lynx -cookies=1 -accept_all_cookies=1 -cookie_file=cookie.file $URL

if it's going to be of any help - here's the trace:

> parse_arg(arg_name=-cookies=1, mask=1, count=2)
>   parse_arg lookup(cookies=1)
>   ...skip (mask 1/4)
>   parse_arg(arg_name=-accept_all_cookies=1, mask=1, count=3)
>   parse_arg lookup(accept_all_cookies=1)
>   ...skip (mask 1/4)
>   parse_arg(arg_name=-cookie_file=cookie.file, mask=1, count=4)
>   parse_arg lookup(cookie_file=cookie.file)
>   ...skip (mask 1/4)
>   parse_arg(arg_name=$URL, mask=1, count=5)
>   parse_arg startfile:$URL

obvious question, why? the actual difference, from what i see, is the inability to trigger "PERSISTENT_COOKIES:TRUE" by command-line options in lynx. or, maybe, i have overlooked/misunderstood something?

Comment: yes, indeed, i have verified that the issue is only related to that one setting, as this seems to work just fine:  `lynx -cfg=dupe.cfg -cookies -accept_all_cookies -cookie_file=cookie.file $URL`, the only thing "dupe.cfg" contains is "PERSISTENT_COOKIES:TRUE". however, my question still remains - how does one activate this setting via the command line?

Comment: great Q - +1 in hopes of finding you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following document implies that you can get this behavior by compiling Lynx with the `--enable-persistent-cookies` flag. The behavior is disabled by default, but implied to be enabled with this configuration flag.

You can use `checkinstall` or similar to easily create a package for your system from source.

Source: http://lynx.isc.org/release/lynx2-8-7/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#Cookies

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `-cookie_save_file` to the same file.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue for me.